# How to add two Integer classes(instanceof)

Tags: java, instanceof

I've implemented this method:

```
    public static Object findInstance(Object value);
```

Method takes object value and convertes class type(if possible) to Integer or Double.
After invoking findInstance,I want to check my class type,something like this:

```
    value.getClass();
```

The result is java.lang.Double or java.lang.Integer.(as expected)

But I cant call any of methods from Integer(or Double) class on that object.

Final result should be:

```
    value1=findInstance(value1);
    value2=findInstance(value2);
    int sum=value1.intValue()+value2.intValue();
    System.out.println("Sum:"+sum);
```

Can someone explain why can't I call method intValue() ?

Comment: Because the type of your object may be Integer, but the type of your variable is Object.

Comment: Ok,I was aiming for that,but I have no clue how to fix this.
After method findInstance is called,I want to be completely sure that I have right class type.
Then I have 2 options:
1) change prototype to public static void findInstance(Object value)
But then findInstance method doesn't make any change.
2) Have more then one method or in main class have if condition checking if the type is right(ugly and not really good solution)

Answer (score 2):

A few comments on this:
First, azurefrog states the correct reason: your variable is of type Object, not of type Number.

Second: if you want to conditionally invoke intValue() or doubleValue() on the object, have your method return a variable of type Number instead of type Object.

Third: I do not know the task you are performing, so you may have very good reason for doing this.  Nevertheless, try to write your code in such a way that will not require cast operations of any sort or invocations of instanceof.  Usually, the presence of these operations is a sign of a 'design smell'.  It might not be in your case, but it seems a bit fishy in my not-always-so-humble-opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Note that BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short implements Number interface (these classes will pass is-a Number test), so you don't have to "findInstance" of them. You can use Number interface:

```
if(obj instanceof Number) {
    Number number = (Number) obj;
    int value = number.intValue();
    ...
}
```